# Azure Functions SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

After upgrading to 1.0.1 CLI tools without any code changes, I suddenly started to get the following error:

```
ResizeImage: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ResizeImage'. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB:
 'Id' is required when binding to a DocumentClient property.
```

The following code:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ResizeImage))]
public static async Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("profile-pictures/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, [DocumentDB(databaseName: "x", collectionName: "UserProfile", CreateIfNotExists = true)] DocumentClient client, [Blob("profile-pictures/resized-{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob resizedBlob, TraceWriter log)
```

I thought Id is optional? At least that's what the docs says.

According to the docs:

> The properties id and sqlQuery cannot both be specified. If neither id
>   nor sqlQuery is set, the entire collection is retrieved.

The generated json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "path": "profile-pictures/{name}",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "myBlob"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "databaseName": "x",
      "collectionName": "UserProfile",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "client"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "profile-pictures/resized-{name}",
      "direction": "inout",
      "name": "resizedBlob"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\X.Functions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "X.Functions.ResizeImage.RunAsync"
}
```

I'm using 1.0.0 SDK

Answer (score 0):

> I thought Id is optional? At least that's what the docs says.

Yes, id is optional. But according to the document of [Azure Functions Cosmos DB bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb). We need to use IEnumerable<dynamic> as the binding type. Please change your code as following.

```
[DocumentDB(...)] IEnumerable<dynamic> documents
```

You will get all the documents from the collection. I tested it and it worked fine on my side.

In addition, the direction should be changed to in if you want to get data from DocumentDB.

```
"direction": "in"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I cannot just modify the generated json as I am using the SDK to generate it on the fly for me depending on the attributes and type definition on my function.

Comment: Have you changed the binding type to IEnumerable<dynamic> and will that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it did not. It's a known bug apparently and will be fixed in the future.

Comment: Very strange, I can get the expected result after changed the binding type to IEnumerable<dynamic> on my test machine. I'm using 1.0.0 SDK too.

Comment: If you open your `func.exe.config` what's your `Documents.Client` binding redirect?

Comment: I can't find the func.exe.config file on my side. The binding direction in function.json file is in.